# Styling TreeVirtual widget

Tags: widget, styling, qooxdoo

I'm using a qooxdoo TreeVirtual widget to display permissions by role in my web application, and I want to apply some styles in my tree virtual. For example, I want to change the + and - icons to expand and collapse the branches, and also I want to change the style of Boolean cell rendered, make the checkbox bigger. How can I style the tree virtual?
  [See image here of my tree virtual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDxXg.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you probably don't realize it, you are actually asking two independent questions here. TreeVirtual is a special case of the Table widget. The tree column uses a cell renderer called SimpleTreeDataCellRenderer. The other columns are just ordinary Table cell renderers. So, the two parts of your question are:

1. How do I change the icons used by the SimpleTreeDataCellRenderer?
2. How do I alter the Boolean cell renderer to do my bidding?

For #1... The SimpleTreeDataCellRenderer uses icons selected from the application's appearance theme. To be specific, the open & close icons are selected based on the "treevirtual-folder" style. You'll find this defined in qooxdoo, e.g., in the modern theme, in qx/theme/modern/Appearance.js (classname qx.theme.modern.Appearance). Your own app has a `theme` directory as well which overrides a qooxdoo theme. You can place your own style for "treevirtual-folder" into your app's theme's `Appearance.js` file. It will look something like the following, added to the `appearances` member, to replicate what the qooxdoo theme does. You can customize it from there to use icons in your app's resources directories.

```
    "treevirtual-folder" :
    {
      style : function(states)
      {
        return {
          icon : states.opened ?
            "icon/16/places/folder-open.png" :
            "icon/16/places/folder.png"
        };
      }
    }
```

For #2... The icons used by the Boolean cell renderer are defined in properties `iconTrue` and `iconFalse`. These are string properties with a relative path within the resources directory. They default to `decoration/table/boolean-true.png` and `decoration/table/boolean-false.png`, respectively, which are paths that are found within the qooxdoo theme if your app does not provide such paths.

More sophisticated changes to a cell renderer are made by extending an existing cell renderer with a class in your app, and specifying its use after you instantiate the Table or TreeVirtual.

I recommend reviewing the documentation on [appearance themes](https://www.qooxdoo.org/docs/#/desktop/gui/theming).

Hope that helps.

Derrell

Comment: Awesome!!! Great explanation, and thanks for clarifying what I wrote.. I apologize, my native language is Spanish,  I'm still learning English, that's the reason I'm not able yet to explain my ideas very well.